# How to import predicates in Strawberry Prolog?

Tags: prolog

I want to include some predicates from other file.
for example
file "task2"

```
nsk(A,B,NSK) :-nsd(A,B,NSD),NSK is (A*B)/NSD.

?- nsk(16,4,NSK),write(NSK).
```

How include "nsd" predicate from file "task11" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming the predicate is defined in file `task11.pl` you should be able to issue

```
 ?- consult([task11]).
```